# How to enable submit button when input fields are filled dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made a web form where a user can fill Input fields by using a drop down box. Fields are dynamically filled using Jquery help. When all Input fields are filled, user have to click Submit Button to further use my Form benefits. I don't want to let users use Submit button till all input fields are filled. For this, I have already added a function in my code. This function enables Submit button only when all the input fields are filled with some amount. but issue is arising when input fields are filled dynamically using drop down box. when fields are filled using the drop down box , Submit button is not getting enabled itself. I have to click one of the input field to enable it.

I tried Google also to solve this issue but unable to solve this on my own. 
Can someone please help me to solve this issue.

Here is my code

```js
let headings = []
function initInputs(headingList) {
  jQuery(".fields").append(createInputsHTML(headingList))
}


function createInputsHTML(headingList) {
  let html = ''
  headingList.forEach(heading => {
    if (heading !== 'Company') {
      html += `<label for="${heading}">${heading}: </label>`
      html += `<input type="number" id="${heading}">`
      html += '<br>'
    }
  })

  return html
}


function getJSON() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    jQuery.get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.coasilat.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/data-1.txt", function(data) {
      resolve(JSON.parse(data))
    });
  })
}

// processing raw JSON data
function processRawData(data) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const companyData = []
    // creating data array
    // handling multiple sheets
    Object.values(data).forEach((sheet, index) => {
      sheet.forEach((company, i) => {
        companyData.push({ ...company
        })
        // create headings only once
        if (index === 0 && i === 0) {
          Object.keys(company).forEach(item => {
            headings.push(item.trim())
          })
        }
      })
    })
    resolve(companyData)
  })
}

$(async function() {

  let lists = [];

  function initAutocomplete(list) {
    const thisKey = 'Company'
    $("#company").autocomplete('option', 'source', function(request, response) {
      response(
        list.filter(item => {
          if (item[thisKey].toLowerCase().includes(request.term.toLowerCase())) {
            item.label = item[thisKey]
            return item
          }
        })
      )
    })
  }

  $("#company").autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: lists,
    focus: function(event, ui) {
      // the "species" is constant - it shouldn't be modified
      $("#company").val(ui.item.Company);
      return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      // handling n number of fields / columns
      headings.forEach(heading => {
        $('#' + heading).val(ui.item[heading])
      })
      return false;
    }
  });

  // starting data download, processing and usage
  getJSON()
    .then(json => {
      return processRawData(json)
    })
    .then(data => {
      
      // make the processed data accessible globally
      lists = data
      initAutocomplete(lists)
      initInputs(headings)
    })

});



// code to set default values if user enters zero or negative values




//calculation for Rating value

$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#Cal").click(function(){

var peVal=0,roceVal=0,sgVal=0,dyVal=0,psVal=0,pbVal=0,npmlqVal=0,roaVal=0,deVal=0,upsVal=0,crVal=0
;

jQuery(".fields input").each(function (){ 
var idHeading=$(this).attr("id");  

if(idHeading=="PE"){ peVal=parseInt($(this).val()); } 
if(idHeading=="ROCE"){ roceVal=parseInt($(this).val()); } 
if(idHeading=="SG"){ sgVal=parseInt($(this).val()); } 
if(idHeading=="DY"){ dyVal=parseFloat($(this).val()); } 
if(idHeading=="PS"){ psVal=parseFloat($(this).val()); }
if(idHeading=="PB"){ pbVal=parseFloat($(this).val()); }
if(idHeading=="NPMLQ"){ npmlqVal=parseFloat($(this).val()); }

if(idHeading=="ROA"){ roaVal=parseFloat($(this).val()); }
if(idHeading=="DE"){ deVal=parseFloat($(this).val()); }
if(idHeading=="UPS"){ upsVal=parseFloat($(this).val()); }
if(idHeading=="CR"){ crVal=parseFloat($(this).val()); }


}); 

var output=peVal+roceVal+sgVal+dyVal+psVal+pbVal+npmlqVal+roaVal+deVal+upsVal+crVal
;

$("output[name='amount']").text(output);
 }); 
 });
 
 
 $(document).on("keyup", "input[type='number']", function() {
  var empty = false;
  $('input[type="number"]').each(function() {
    if (($(this).val() == '')) {
      empty = true;
    }
  });

  if (empty) {
    $('#Cal').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
    $('#Cal').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        
<div class="ui-widget">
  <form id="frm1">
    <label for="company">Drop-down box </label>
    <input id="company"><br /><br />
    
    <div class="fields"></div>
    <!-- PLEASE NOTE THAT THE OTHER INPUT FIELDS WILL BE ADDED DYNAMICALLY -->
 <button  type="button" id="Cal" disabled="disabled"  >
 Button
 </button>
<p> <output name="amount" for="calculation">0</output>
</p>
</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use ``required`` flag for your fields and ``type="submit"`` for your button, HTML5 will do the job and you don't need to disable the button, but don't forget to check data in server side.

Comment: So trigger the validation code when you update the fields

Comment: @Gonzalo I can't use Required attribute due to some of my own reasons. I am trying to resolve this issue using some changes in my JavaScript code. Thanks in advance

Comment: @epascarello can you please provide me a working example. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: @epascarello can you please edit my code with your suggestion and share me the update version. I had tried this thing but then i was unable to properly run my code. Thanks in advance

Comment: so you tried `.val("foo").trigger('keyup')`

Comment: @epascarello I mean to say that I had tried such things but due to my lack coding experience, I was not able to solve my problem on my own. Thats why, I am seeking help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last `keyup` of your code is ok (`$(document).on("keyup", "input[type='number']", ... );`) but you forgot that it will only trigger when the event `keyup` trigger in the `input`s with the attribute `type='number'`.

This event will not fire when you select something in the autocomplete input, you need to add some code to check it. Something like:

```js
let headings = []
function initInputs(headingList) {
 jQuery(".fields").append(createInputsHTML(headingList))
}


function createInputsHTML(headingList) {
 let html = ''
 headingList.forEach(heading => {
  if (heading !== 'Company') {
   html += `<label for="${heading}">${heading}: </label>`
   html += `<input type="number" id="${heading}">`
   html += '<br>'
  }
 })

 return html
}


function getJSON() {
 return new Promise(resolve => {
  jQuery.get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.coasilat.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/data-1.txt", function(data) {
   resolve(JSON.parse(data))
  });
 })
}

// processing raw JSON data
function processRawData(data) {
 return new Promise(resolve => {
  const companyData = []
  // creating data array
  // handling multiple sheets
  Object.values(data).forEach((sheet, index) => {
   sheet.forEach((company, i) => {
    companyData.push({ ...company
    })
    // create headings only once
    if (index === 0 && i === 0) {
     Object.keys(company).forEach(item => {
      headings.push(item.trim())
     })
    }
   })
  })
  resolve(companyData)
 })
}

$(async function() {

 let lists = [];

 function initAutocomplete(list) {
  const thisKey = 'Company'
  $("#company").autocomplete('option', 'source', function(request, response) {
   response(
    list.filter(item => {
     if (item[thisKey].toLowerCase().includes(request.term.toLowerCase())) {
      item.label = item[thisKey]
      return item
     }
    })
   )
  })
 }

 $("#company").autocomplete({
  minLength: 1,
  source: lists,
  focus: function(event, ui) {
   // the "species" is constant - it shouldn't be modified
   $("#company").val(ui.item.Company);
   return false;
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
      var empty = false;
   // handling n number of fields / columns
   headings.forEach(heading => {
    $('#' + heading).val(ui.item[heading]);
        if ((ui.item[heading] == '')) {
          empty = true;
        }
   });
      checkFill(empty);
   return false;
  }
 });

 // starting data download, processing and usage
 getJSON()
  .then(json => {
   return processRawData(json)
  })
  .then(data => {
   
   // make the processed data accessible globally
   lists = data
   initAutocomplete(lists)
   initInputs(headings)
  })

});



// code to set default values if user enters zero or negative values




//calculation for Rating value

$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#Cal").click(function(){

var peVal=0,roceVal=0,sgVal=0,dyVal=0,psVal=0,pbVal=0,npmlqVal=0,roaVal=0,deVal=0,upsVal=0,crVal=0
;

jQuery(".fields input").each(function (){ 
var idHeading=$(this).attr("id");  

if(idHeading=="PE"){ peVal=parseInt($(this).val()); } 
if(idHeading=="ROCE"){ roceVal=parseInt($(this).val()); } 
if(idHeading=="SG"){ sgVal=parseInt($(this).val()); } 
if(idHeading=="DY"){ dyVal=parseFloat($(this).val()); } 
if(idHeading=="PS"){ psVal=parseFloat($(this).val()); }
if(idHeading=="PB"){ pbVal=parseFloat($(this).val()); }
if(idHeading=="NPMLQ"){ npmlqVal=parseFloat($(this).val()); }

if(idHeading=="ROA"){ roaVal=parseFloat($(this).val()); }
if(idHeading=="DE"){ deVal=parseFloat($(this).val()); }
if(idHeading=="UPS"){ upsVal=parseFloat($(this).val()); }
if(idHeading=="CR"){ crVal=parseFloat($(this).val()); }


}); 

var output=peVal+roceVal+sgVal+dyVal+psVal+pbVal+npmlqVal+roaVal+deVal+upsVal+crVal
;

$("output[name='amount']").text(output);
 }); 
 });
 
 
 $(document).on("keyup", "input[type='number']", function() {
 var empty = false;
 $('input[type="number"]').each(function() {
  if (($(this).val() == '')) {
   empty = true;
  }
 });
  checkFill(empty);
});

function checkFill(isEmpty){
  if (isEmpty) {
  $('#Cal').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
 } else {
  $('#Cal').removeAttr('disabled');
 }
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="ui-widget">
    <form id="frm1">
   <label for="company">Drop-down box </label>
   <input id="company"><br /><br />
    <div class="fields"></div>
    <!-- PLEASE NOTE THAT THE OTHER INPUT FIELDS WILL BE ADDED DYNAMICALLY -->
     <button  type="button" id="Cal" disabled="disabled"  >
     Button
     </button>
    <p> <output name="amount" for="calculation">0</output>
    </p>
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Or, at least, trigger the [`keyup`](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) function when you set the field value:

```js
let headings = []
function initInputs(headingList) {
 jQuery(".fields").append(createInputsHTML(headingList))
}


function createInputsHTML(headingList) {
 let html = ''
 headingList.forEach(heading => {
  if (heading !== 'Company') {
   html += `<label for="${heading}">${heading}: </label>`
   html += `<input type="number" id="${heading}">`
   html += '<br>'
  }
 })

 return html
}


function getJSON() {
 return new Promise(resolve => {
  jQuery.get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.coasilat.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/data-1.txt", function(data) {
   resolve(JSON.parse(data))
  });
 })
}

// processing raw JSON data
function processRawData(data) {
 return new Promise(resolve => {
  const companyData = []
  // creating data array
  // handling multiple sheets
  Object.values(data).forEach((sheet, index) => {
   sheet.forEach((company, i) => {
    companyData.push({ ...company
    })
    // create headings only once
    if (index === 0 && i === 0) {
     Object.keys(company).forEach(item => {
      headings.push(item.trim())
     })
    }
   })
  })
  resolve(companyData)
 })
}

$(async function() {

 let lists = [];

 function initAutocomplete(list) {
  const thisKey = 'Company'
  $("#company").autocomplete('option', 'source', function(request, response) {
   response(
    list.filter(item => {
     if (item[thisKey].toLowerCase().includes(request.term.toLowerCase())) {
      item.label = item[thisKey]
      return item
     }
    })
   )
  })
 }

 $("#company").autocomplete({
  minLength: 1,
  source: lists,
  focus: function(event, ui) {
   // the "species" is constant - it shouldn't be modified
   $("#company").val(ui.item.Company);
   return false;
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
   // handling n number of fields / columns
   headings.forEach(heading => {
    $('#' + heading).val(ui.item[heading]).keyup();
   })
   return false;
  }
 });

 // starting data download, processing and usage
 getJSON()
  .then(json => {
   return processRawData(json)
  })
  .then(data => {
   
   // make the processed data accessible globally
   lists = data
   initAutocomplete(lists)
   initInputs(headings)
  })

});



// code to set default values if user enters zero or negative values




//calculation for Rating value

$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#Cal").click(function(){

var peVal=0,roceVal=0,sgVal=0,dyVal=0,psVal=0,pbVal=0,npmlqVal=0,roaVal=0,deVal=0,upsVal=0,crVal=0
;

jQuery(".fields input").each(function (){ 
var idHeading=$(this).attr("id");  

if(idHeading=="PE"){ peVal=parseInt($(this).val()); } 
if(idHeading=="ROCE"){ roceVal=parseInt($(this).val()); } 
if(idHeading=="SG"){ sgVal=parseInt($(this).val()); } 
if(idHeading=="DY"){ dyVal=parseFloat($(this).val()); } 
if(idHeading=="PS"){ psVal=parseFloat($(this).val()); }
if(idHeading=="PB"){ pbVal=parseFloat($(this).val()); }
if(idHeading=="NPMLQ"){ npmlqVal=parseFloat($(this).val()); }

if(idHeading=="ROA"){ roaVal=parseFloat($(this).val()); }
if(idHeading=="DE"){ deVal=parseFloat($(this).val()); }
if(idHeading=="UPS"){ upsVal=parseFloat($(this).val()); }
if(idHeading=="CR"){ crVal=parseFloat($(this).val()); }


}); 

var output=peVal+roceVal+sgVal+dyVal+psVal+pbVal+npmlqVal+roaVal+deVal+upsVal+crVal
;

$("output[name='amount']").text(output);
 }); 
 });
 
 
 $(document).on("keyup", "input[type='number']", function() {
 var empty = false;
 $('input[type="number"]').each(function() {
  if (($(this).val() == '')) {
   empty = true;
  }
 });

 if (empty) {
  $('#Cal').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
 } else {
  $('#Cal').removeAttr('disabled');
 }
});
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="ui-widget">
    <form id="frm1">
   <label for="company">Drop-down box </label>
   <input id="company"><br /><br />
    <div class="fields"></div>
    <!-- PLEASE NOTE THAT THE OTHER INPUT FIELDS WILL BE ADDED DYNAMICALLY -->
     <button  type="button" id="Cal" disabled="disabled"  >
     Button
     </button>
    <p> <output name="amount" for="calculation">0</output>
    </p>
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please share a Js fiddle of it. It will be easier for me to understand. Thanks in advance

Comment: @user11651048 changed the examples to snippets. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for you answer @KL_. It really worked for me. But when I tried to use it on other platform, it is not working properly. Can you please check what is the issue. I will be very grateful. Here is a link https://code.sololearn.com/WDvn2B98xMkA

Comment: @user11651048 you forgot to check the input changes in the select of autocomplete (l.86 - 92).

Comment: Sorry friend but I can't understand what you are trying to say. Can you please share me the solution of this? Thanks in advance @KL_

Comment: @user11651048 you aren't checking each input value after the autocomplete. You can achieve this by triggering the `keyup` event. Add `.keyup()` in the line 88 of your snippet js.